# How to Export dataList to Excel and PDF using Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 5.0.jar. I have one datalist and i want to export the datalist value, in primeface showcase datattable export option only avaiable. How can i achieve this?

Comment: You could have at least added a question mark to your "question"...

Comment: you got any reliable answer?

Comment: @Irfan Nasim i didn't get any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces has dataexporter.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml

Also you can write your custom exporters.
Visit http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/customExporter.jsf